# assign a php variable to a sessionStorage var

Tags: php, html, sessionstorage

I am trying to set a php variable value to a HTML5 sessionStorage. Is this feasible? Check my code below:

```
<script>sessionStorage.username = </script><php echo $_GET["user"]; ?>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your question is very poor, did you try this code? what errors do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    sessionStorage.username = '<?php echo $_GET["user"]; ?>';
</script>
```

Code edited

Comment: `<php` should be `<?php`

Comment: That one works thank you for this. but i think sessionStorage will not help me with my security checks. What i am trying to implement is to avoid php session variables to perform a check if a page is being accessed by a logged in user or not. so i need at the top of each page to perform a check and avoid session mixture with multiple tabs open. The scenario being: i am logged in to my system using a user with specific privileges, if another tab is opened and admin tries to log in then it becomes a mess with php session variables as the privileges access gets mixed up :)